# Как проверить текстовый файл на его наличие или отсутствие?

Tags: c++, fstream

Есть код написанный на С++, в нём используется библиотека fstream, с её помощью создаётся текстовый файл. Пользователь сам вводит имя текстового файла. Как сделать проверку на наличие уже существующего имени файла, чтобы пользователь не мог создать два файла с одинаковым именем? Так как, если пользователь вводит уже существующее имя файла, файл перезаписывается и данные файла удаляются

```
ofstream f1;    // Запись в файл
ifstream f2;    // Чтение из файла

char namef[20];
cout << "Введите имя файла" << "\n";
cin.get (namef, 20);
const char txt[5] = ".txt";

strcat_s(namef, txt);



f1.open(namef);





f1.close();


system("pause");
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists?

Comment: Два файла с *полностью одинаковым именем* создать в принципе нельзя (по очевидной причине ОС этого не позволяет (т.к. сама не может))

Comment: так как операция не может быть атомной, поможет попытка сначала открыть на чтение. [StackOverflowEng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818099/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-before-creating-a-new-file)